# Vi or Vim not found on Ubuntu docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vi

I have an nginx-controller container running in k8s based on an Ubuntu image:

```
Image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.25.0
```

Inside the container:

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-xyz bash
$ uname -a
Linux nginx-ingress-controller-xyz 4.15.0-1111-azure #123~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 01:52:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Seems that neither **vi** or **vim** is available:

```
$ vi
bash: vi: command not found
$ vim
bash: vim: command not found
```

I thought vi/vim would always be on a linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `vi` command that behaves as per [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) is mandatory for an OS to call itself Unix.

Ubuntu and other Linux-based operating systems are not certified and being certified is not exactly a goal so all they do is follow the specification as closely as they want/need/can. Therefore, it is unreasonable to expect vi to "always be on a linux machine" or that `vi` command to be provided by Vim. There is simply no guarantee.

Moreover, it is customary to make Docker images meant for production as lightweight (and secure) as possible by removing as much cruft as possible. You don't need `vi` to run your Ingress Controller so it isn't there.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find many commonly available programs in docker images. Because these images are made to be lightweight.
You can install vim on an ubuntu image by

```
apt-get update && apt-get install vim
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, For me, this method always works.
At first go to your container and then use these commands:

```
apt update
apt install vim
```

or

```
apt update
apt install nano
```

Comment: apt is not on the container/image either so that will not work

Answer (score 0):

If there is `apt` or `apt-get` command in your container, just run `apt update && apt install vim`, otherwise you can try:
`nsenter -t <Pid> -n -m vi <your-file>` to reuse the tools on your host but change the namespace.